# How to check the state of the phone without waiting for a state change

Tags: android

In Android, I currently use onCallStateChanged to detect any changes in the state of a phone. However, I would like to know what the state of the phone is without having to wait for a change in the state. For example, I want the app to automatically dial a number but need to know if the phone is already in use (off the hook).

Comment: Nope. That indicates state changes. As stated in my post, I need to query the state without detecting any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html). You can query it at any time, as long as you have the permission declared.